# Phaser button doesn't call a function

Tags: jquery, function, button, phaser-framework

I created a button in Phaser:

```
//---------------------------------Boot
module.exports = {

 init: function() {
    closeButton = game.add.button(w/1.47, h/1.272, 'close', this.closeProf, this);
    closeButton.fixedToCamera = true;
    closeButton.inputEnabled = true;
 },

 closeProf: function() {
    alert('aaa')
 }
};
```

Module.exports - this is Browserify.

In the main file there is this code:

```
//---------------------------------Main
window.game = new Phaser.Game((h > w) ? h : w, (h > w) ? w : h, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game', {render:render});

var ship;
var cursors;
var sun1;
var rc;
var space;

var profile;
var closeButton, holdLeft, holdRight, avaProfile;

game.state.add('Boot', require('./states/boot.js'));
game.state.add('Play', require('./states/play.js'));
game.state.start('Boot');
```

How do I make the button call a function?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is calling `closeProf` on itself. Before you create the button, add a variable `var that = this`.
Do not add a context, it means you are calling `this.this.closeProf`.

Your button code should look like this:

```
module.exports = {

  init: function() {
    var that = this;
    closeButton = game.add.button(w/1.47, h/1.272, 'close', that.closeProf);
    closeButton.fixedToCamera = true;
    closeButton.inputEnabled = true;
 },

 closeProf: function() {
    alert('aaa')
 }
};
```